# Cleaning up the vague [function] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) is, in my opinion, an incredibly vague tag, that overlaps significantly with [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming). The tag wiki of [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) only has an excerpt that reads

> For challenges that ask for a function or involve functions in some way. (Also known as methods or subroutines.)

Taking a browse through the 48 [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) questions, they can be sorted into 3 categories:

- Questions that ask answerers to submit a function as their solution. If this is the intended usage of [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function), then it makes it a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and this already falls under our program defaults (functions and programs)
- Questions that fall under the [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag, such as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216923/i-dont-like-curry)
- Questions that ask answerers to craft a mathematical function with specific requirements. For example, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/define-a-function-f-such-that-ffn-n-for-all-non-zero-integers-n) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115507/fgx-decreases-while-gfx-increases).

The first and second categories should not be appropriate usage of [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function). They are covered by our site defaults, and the [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag, respectively.

The third is a legitimate style of question that we should welcome on the site. I also think this was the original usage of the [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) tag. However, it's currently being confused with other, more vague uses of the word "function". As [suggested by Bubbler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57702550#57702550), [mathematical-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-function) or similar would be a better name.

---

This discussion is to answer the following questions:

- Should we clean up the [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) tag?
- If so, how?

  - Should we remove it from posts in category 1, synonymize [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) with [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) and tag relevant questions with a new [mathematical-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-function) tag?
  - Something else?

What are your thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but some thoughts that wouldn't fit in a comment.

### I don't think that [mathematical-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-function) is a very good name.

The challenges in category 3 have an *interesting* unifying feature: the fact that they don't mandate particular outputs, but require some property to be true. They do all involve mathematical functions, because mathematical functions are a good language to describe properties.  They are not *about* functions as much as they are about properties. There are many other challenges that do involve mathematical functions or are even *about* a particular mathematical function (e.g. Fibonacci, factorial etc.). Anything with [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) has a high probability of involving mathematical functions.

I think calling it [mathematical-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-function), just creates another tag with a vague name, which may very well end up slapped on all sorts of stuff.

The posts here have an *interesting* unifying feature that not all function related challenges have. So our tag should have a name that captures this feature.

---

### I suggest [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function)

I think the key feature we want though is a name that doesn't cause people to jump to the wrong conclusion and end up tagging a bunch of random challenges.  This makes the tag useless.

For these reasons I suggest [open-ended-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended-function).  This expresses the open-endedness that unifies them and is hard to misinterpret as something else. It probably isn't clear at first sight what this means, but I think that just means newbies click on the tag to read the description, while experienced users will just know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

### Create [define-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/define-function) and [blackbox-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackbox-function)

I agree with Wheat Wizard in that [mathematical-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-function) is vague. For questions that require defining/finding mathematical functions that meet some critera, [define-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/define-function) may be a better name.

There are also some questions that involve taking blackbox functions as input but don't have to do with functional programming. If there are enough of them, I think the tag [blackbox-function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackbox-function) would be appropriate.